# android scrolldown onCreate

Tags: android, scroll

I would like to know how to automatically scroll a activity to the bottom.
I have this in my button where "sv" is my ScrollView:

```
sv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);  //it works only in the button
```

But when I do it in the onCreate method nothing happens.
I also tried it with threads but nothing happens.

Could someone help me please.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollview.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```

The scrollview must be created first, then you can scroll down. That's why we use `post()` here.